# How can I disable an Azure Redis Cache?

Tags: azure, redis

I have been experimenting with the Azure Redis Cache preview, and so far, so good. However, when I am not using it, I would like to disable it so that it is not consuming memory and not accessible.

I would prefer not to delete it, as I do not wish to create a new instance each time I want to run some tests. But from the portal, there is no disable or deactivate option, just delete.

I have reviewed the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690523.aspx but have not found a solution.

Comment: I was unable to disable it but I changed the key so nobody could use it any more. In my case my biggest worry was that someone might be using it. After a few days I will be able to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find an answer through the Azure Cache forum on MSDN.

For the time being, there is no deactivate or disable command. And under the Preview release, some of the Redis commands, such as SHUTDOWN, have been disabled.

For more information, see:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/3730b7d1-f0bd-4a02-b35e-e0078ba1bba4/how-can-i-disable-an-azure-redis-cache?forum=azurecache

Comment: There is no pause support still...
"There is no option for stopping or pausing the billing of a cache."
Source: [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#how-am-i-billed-for-azure-redis-cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#how-am-i-billed-for-azure-redis-cache)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same requirement where I want to disable the cache to do some testing. I had to work around by using FireWall option and input a random ip that isn't mines.

[image]

Comment: Best workaround so far